# Webpack.config.js doesn't want to use an appriopriate loader to handle PNG images

Tags: npm, webpack, leaflet

I use in my project two library:

```
"leaflet": "^1.0.3",
"react-leaflet": "^1.9.1",
```

I import following styles in my **map.less** file:

```
@import "../../../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

I see some errors related to png files included in leaflet package. One of them is below:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"minimize":true}!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css 7:6181-6216
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--5-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./src/app/components/toolkit/monitor-management/monitor-management-settings/map.less
```

This is my webpack config:

```
const config = {
    some aliases outputs, entries etc...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
                ],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/react'
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
                            'babel-plugin-jsx-remove-data-test-id'
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'modules/src')
                ],
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                minimize: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: function () {
                                    return [
                                        require('autoprefixer')
                                    ];
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'less-loader',
                            options: {}
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/img')
                ],
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: '/fonts/',
                    publicPath: '/login/fonts/'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png|jp(e*)g)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/img')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10, // Convert images to base64 strings
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: '/img/',
                            publicPath: '/login/img/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    some plugins...
}
```

**In my opinion I would be able to load png thanks to url-loader.**

Maybe the reason is in another place. Maybe sould I use file-loader to handle this case?

Comment: I think you might have to use the `css-loader` (already installed) since you are importing `css` file directly. The rule you have written considers only `less` files. I am not 100% sure, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is about requiring an image from `node_modules` specifically in this case `node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png`. However, the `url-loader` is set up just handling this only: `path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/img')` that's why all images in other places can't be handled.

Normally you can either add more paths into it or completely remove it (this is what I prefer):

```js
{
  test: /\.(svg|png|jp(e*)g)$/,
  // Remove this
  // include: [
  //    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/img')
  // ],
  use: [
    // ...
  ]
},
```